# Unset variable(s) for each array object

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to know if there is any way to simplify this:

```php
$transactions = $database->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user = :user", array(":user" => $USER["id"]));
$transactions_cleaned = array();

foreach($transactions as $transaction){
    unset($transaction["id"]);
    unset($transaction["user"]);

    array_push($transactions_cleaned, $transaction);
}
```

It basically removes each `id` and `user` variables for each object of the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user] => 1
            [type] => deposit
            [amount] => 1000
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user] => 1
            [type] => withdraw
            [amount] => 1000
        )
)
```

So it becomes like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => deposit
            [amount] => 1000
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => withdraw
            [amount] => 1000
        )
)
```

Comment: you can use `foreach($transactions as &$transaction){` to unset  from origin array

Comment: Why are you get id,user from query if you don't want.

Comment: Just do not get ID and User in Query, instead of *, write `Type` and `Amount`

Comment: Update your query to `SELECT type, amount FROM transactions WHERE user = :user`. The `*` means select every column

Comment: There are much columns, I'd like to keep my SQL query as it.

Comment: @mfort This seem to work well, thank you. However, would there be any faster way than doing it like that? https://pastebin.com/SiCWzvmD

Comment: array_walk($transactions , function ($item, $key) use (&$transactions) 
                        {
                            unset($transactions[$key]['id']);
                            unset($transactions[$key]['user']);
                        })

Comment: in php the faster way that i suggest is build other query like @catcon suggestion

Comment: @Laiteux selecting specific columns will automatically improve your code execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [mfort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8353201/mfort) and also [Sagar Sainkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11646313/sagar-sainkar) even if yours is more complex:

```php
$transactions = $database->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user = :user", array(":user" => $USER["id"]));

foreach($transactions as &$transaction){
    unset($transaction["id"]);
    unset($transaction["user"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want do that with in one line and without using foreach

```
<?php


array_walk($transactions , function ($item, $key) use (&$transactions) 
                        {
                            unset($transactions[$key]['id']);
                            unset($transactions[$key]['user']);
                        });



?>
```